# Firebase Functions doesn't update require'd files

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a project that uses Functions, structured like so

**`functions/index.js`**

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const endpoints = require('./endpoints.js')

// Other functions goes here...

exports.endpoints = functions.https.onRequest(endpoints)
```

**`functions/endpoints.js`**

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/endpoints', (req, res) => { res.end('Hello, world!') }

module.exports = app
```

The `endpoints` function is meant for providing `<meta>` tags to social media crawlers, which is a difficult task to do conventionally since I'm using SPA. It's accessed using rewrites

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/share{,/**}",
    "function": "endpoints"
  },
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

Right now I'm just testing it on one URL https://www.amborjo.com/share

I made a mistake of not including the correct URL for normal browsers to redirect to. But I can't seem to change it since the changes doesn't seem to affect the contents of the HTML the function returns.

The problem is, I'm making changes to `endpoints.js` but it doesn't seem to be deployed upon calling `firebase deploy --only functions`. I changed the `Hello, world!` part with some other strings but browsing into the function's URL doesn't show the changes.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How do you know it's not being deployed?  Please edit the question with your observations.

Comment: @DougStevenson I changed the `Hello World` part but refreshing the page, even from Private Browsing doesn't show the change.

Comment: We need more information.  Please show the output of the deploy command that shows if the function was deployed.  Also show how you're accessing the function.  We should be able to duplicate the issue using the steps you provide.

Comment: Looks like it's a caching issue. The problem is solved without me doing anything.